Getting data from IPFS or API to chainlink and to Etherium smartcontract
I have this link "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmV1zn4iskhjpz12UyDrRjTvoTwMVdUGCUYQHpzgjFsHk5?filename=data.json" this returns simple json data {
"data": "testing"
}. so i want to get that data to my smart contract.
how to setup all the things actually? like im really new to this so, im building this in sepolia testnet and using remix for now. so i need to get that data and just printed there with a function call thats it. after that i can build more actually. And also is there any way that i can even send data back to IPFS through this oracles just curious. im having this question because im vexed with LLMs. i cant able to understand from that knowledge, syntax errors etc. and even they got dumb so.

You should use Chainlink Functions for that. Even making HTTP POST requests is possible.
Chainlink Functions provides your smart contracts access to trust-minimized compute infrastructure, allowing you to fetch data from APIs and perform custom computation. Your smart contract sends source code (in JavaScript for now) in a request to a Decentralized Oracle Network (DON), and each node in the DON executes the code in a serverless environment. The DON then aggregates all the independent return values from each execution and sends the final result back to your smart contract.

That means i dont need external adaptors?

So it might depend on the end goal? Generally you'll have offchain data stored on IPFS and the CID is printed onchain like ipfs://CID. If you need to update it then you would have a function on the smart contract that updates the string. If you're trying to do the inverse where the smart contract interprets the IPFS data it would still be easier to have a middleware that interprets and feeds back into the contract.
